# How to fix combine plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm doing the heart function in R.

I wrote it down and the plot doesn't show whole function in cordinate-axis.

```
x<-seq(-1,1,0.001)
length(x)
m<-c(abs(x)^1/2)
n<-c((1-x^2)^1/2)
y1<-c(m+n)
y2<-c(m-n)
plot(x,y2,type="l",col="red",)
lines(x,y1,col="red")
```

It looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytQZU.jpg
I'can't handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first `plot` function determines the axis range, therefor the max and min of `y2` were used.
Combine both and pass them to `ylim`.

```
plot(x,y2,type="l",col="red",ylim = c(min(y1,y2),max(y1,y2)))
lines(x,y1,col="red")
```

[image]